Separate clipboards per space
Is it possible to configure macOS to have separate clipboards for each desktop space?
I want the clipboard to switch automatically when I switch to a different desktop. The reason is that I have some background processes that output its results to the clipboard, and I need them to be available for pasting in the correct desktop space.

There is no such built-in capability within the OS; but there are a large number of third-party applications, usually described as 'clipboard managers', which provide all kinds of additional functionality.
Usually this takes the form of 'multiple' clipboards, or a clipboard history, so that you can select what you're going to paste from a range of things that have been previously copied.
